# Quotient of a polynomial ring localized

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Question:

> Prove that $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(xy)$ localised at $(x-a)$ is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]$ localised at $(x-a)$.

Related question:

> What is the local ring at the point $(0,0)$, i.e. the ring $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(xy)$ localized at $(x,y)$?

I haven't been able to figure it out.

Edit: many thanks to anyone who answers but my main motivation in posting this is to  see that I am doing things properly so I would much appreciate an answer on my solution saying if I have understood something incorrectly or even a downvote/upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First recall that localisation commutes with quotients in the following sense. Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring and $S$ a multiplicatively closed subset. If $\mathfrak{a} \triangleleft R$, then $S^{-1}R/S^{-1}\mathfrak{a} \cong \bar{S}^{-1}(R/\mathfrak{a})$, where $\bar{S}$ is the image of $S$ in $R/\mathfrak{a}$.
 Here we are given that $R=\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$, $ \mathfrak{a}=(XY) $, and $\bar S= ~(x-a)^c.$ Thus $S=(XY,X-a)^c$. Now in the localisation $S^{-1}R$, the ideal $(XY)=(Y)$ and $(XY,X-a)=(Y,X-a)$ as $X$ has now become invertible. Thus, \begin{align}\biggl(\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(XY)\biggr)_{(x-a)}&=\bar S^{-1}\left(R/\mathfrak a\right)\\&\simeq S^{-1}R/S^{-1}
\mathfrak{a}\\&\simeq\mathbb{R}[X,Y]_{(Y,X-a)}/(Y)_{(Y,X-a)}\\&\simeq\mathbb{R}[X]_{(X-a)}\end{align}

The last inequality again employing the commutativity of localisation with quotients.

Comment: What do you mean by the direct sum of rings? Componentwise operations, hence the direct product? Then it is definitely not a local ring, in particularnit cannot be isomorphic to a localisation at a prime...

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake. Thank you, I've edited. Indeed I think nothing can be said about the second part in general, only that it's a non-regular ring.

Comment: Note that you solution to the first problem does not make sense either. You let ideals to be multiplicative systems instead of their complements. The problem is that the question is not even well-posed since $(x-a)$ with $a$ non-zero  is not a prime ideal of the ring $k[x,y]/(xy)$.

Comment: @MooS,are you certain that $(x-a) $ is not a prime ideal?

Comment: Ok, it is actually a prime ideal. However, pointing out the relation between maximal ideals and points, the natural way to note this ideal would be $(x-a,y)$, though it is principal in the quotient.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ring homomorphism $\psi: \mathbb{R[x]}_{(x-a)}\rightarrow\left(\mathbb{R[x,y]}/(xy)\right)_{(x-a)}$ given by inclusion of rational functions $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, where $(x-a)\nmid q(x)$ as this is an element of $\mathbb{R[x]}_{(x-a)}$. This is obviously a ring homomorphism and injective, so we just need to show it is a surjection

Edit to be more specific about inclusions of rational functions: $ \left(\mathbb{R[x,y]}/(xy)\right)_{(x-a)}$ consists of fractions so that the numerator and denominator are polynomials in $x$ and $y$. By "inculsion" I mean "$\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\in \mathbb{R[x]}_{(x-a)}$ is also an element of $ \left(\mathbb{R[x,y]}/(xy)\right)_{(x-a)}$ so it's image under $\psi$ is just  itself". To show it is injective assume that $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=0$ and let $n$ be the lowest power of $x$ in $p(x)$ with coefficent $c_n$. $\frac{1}{x^n}$ is a unit in $\left(\mathbb{R[x,y]}/(xy)\right)_{(x-a)}$ so we find  $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=0     
 \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{x^n} \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=0     
\leftrightarrow up(x)x^{-n}=0$ for some $u$ in $\left(\mathbb{R[x,y]}/(xy)\right)_{(x-a)} \leftrightarrow c_n=0$, and we can repeat this to conclude all coeffeicents of $p(x)$ are zero, so $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ is zero as required

Let $\frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}\in\left(\mathbb{R[x,y]}/(xy)\right)_{(x-a)}$. Then we know 1) $(x-a)\nmid q(x)$ and 2) $xy\nmid q(x,y)$. The polynomial $x$ is invertible in this ring so we find 
$\frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}=1.\frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}=\frac{xp(x,y)}{xq(x,y)}=\frac{\tilde{p}(x)}{\tilde{q}(x)}$ as all '$y$'s will go to zero. This is an element in the image of $\psi$, so $\psi$ is surjective and we are done (I think). The second question is a total mess for me so I wont bother writing it..